# automated way of finding parameters to abstract?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Suppose you have 1000 methods in your solution. You want to do some refactoring by finding methods with common signatures and refactoring them. Is there a standardized method of doing this? **How do you find methods with common signatures or at least 2 of the parameters match?**

Comment: you can use http://www.ndepend.com/ and then write a query to find all methods contains two or more parameters. FYI it uses linq syntax so its very easy to do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible! Go to `ReSharper - Options - Find - Search with Pattern` and create a pattern similar to:

[image]

```
public void $method$($type$ $name$)
{
    $st$
}
```

One more example: [Resharper custom patterns change method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502175/resharper-custom-patterns-change-method-name).

Hint: try `Argument Placeholder` if you don't want to specify exact method's signature.

**EDIT: How to combine more than one pattern in your search?** The workaround: test and save each pattern one by one. Then go to `ReSharper - Options - Code Inspection - Custom Patterns`. Here you should see all patterns you saved before. Set each pattern's severity (dropdownbox) to Error and then go to `ReSharper - Inspect - Solution Errors window`. Turn on `Solution wide analysis` and occurrences of any pattern will be highlighted as errors in this window.

Comment: this is awesome, but i cannot get it to work. for example:

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', set `name` as `identifier` instead of `argument`.

Comment: thank you. here are the results. im not sure i understand what this means? http://i.imgur.com/HzoaYMN.png

Comment: i think i understand! let's say i wanted to search for an int and a string and i wanted it to not pay attention to the order: http://i.imgur.com/LvZmPNz.png somethin glike that, but i would want it to also find: http://i.imgur.com/LwpIZFf.png --- you see how the signature is reversed?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', as I understand, you look for the `OR` statement. Unfortunately, I know only the workaround: try to create two patterns and then combine them in one search. I've updated my answer with details.

Comment: unable to search, am i doing something wrong with my syntax? http://i.imgur.com/FLZEOkP.png  http://i.imgur.com/AMGlhWQ.png

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', it looks like a bug. Could you edit this pattern by double-click?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112714/discussion-between-l-and-ilya-chumakov).